# Smoke not rendering in Cycles - but is baking?! 2.93.1

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, baking, smoke-simulation

I have created a potion with a liquid and smoke, when I bake the simulation everything is great, but when I try to render the animation, everything except the smoke renders?  Help please!!  I am using cycles as my jar is transparent glass and the liquid texture animated.

I am also rendering to a codec with transparent background.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image: Smoke]
[image: Smoke 2]
[image: material on smoke]
[image: This is material for liquid in bottle as the smoke has no amterial]

Material added, still no smoke in render?! [image]

Comment: It would be great if you showed among all those screenshots also one of your smoke material...

Comment:  I have added 2 shots of the emitter and one of the materials now.

Comment: There is no screenshot of the material. A material is found in the _Material Tab_, that is the red checkered sphere symbol above the red chessboard square symbol (the _Texture Tab_ you show in the last screenshot) and below the green triangle symbol. And even better would be the _Shader Editor_ window instead of the material properties. And this material has to be assigned to the domain, not the emitter.

Comment: the smoke does not have a material, the liquid in the bottle does (see screenshot) but the smoke only has a cloud texture.

Comment: And there is your mistake. I guess you should probably watch some basic tutorials on how to make smoke simulations, because to teach you the complete process might be too complex for a simple Q&A.

Comment: You need to have a material on the domain. If you just need a basic material, use the Principal Volume BSDF material and put it in the Volume socket. But put the Principal Volume BSDF Material in the Volume socket and NOT THE Surface socket in the Material Output as  if you put it in the Surface input, it will display the material like a cube since the domain is a cube

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added a material to the container, and the bake looks great, but once again the smoke disappears on render?! (screens uploaded)